# .CDA Not recognizes in batch file since Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: command-line, audio, batch-file, vlc-media-player

We've been using the following batch file for -years- to rip (legal) audio CDs to MP3s for our employees to use on their iPods. But since Windows 10 (Ver 1607 Build 14393.321) they no longer work. I -think- the problem is that for whatever reason, Windows no longer 'sees' the CDA files on the disc drive (at least at the command line). Windows Media Player still recognises the drive and will 'Rip', but that is ultra-tedious. Any way to get this BAT file to work again?

The problem occurs in the FOR loop... ie. the routine exits immediately because the loop can't 'see' any CDA files.

```
FOR /R D:\ %%G IN (D:\*.cda) DO (CALL :TEST_VLC "%%G")

@ECHO OFF
CLS
set OLDDIR=%CD%

SET a=%1
IF %1.==. GOTO :help

SET t=%2
IF %2.==. GOTO :help

SET e=%3
IF %3.==. SET e=mp3

MD %2
CD %2
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@ECHO Ripping %2 from %OLDDIR%
cmd /c wizmo.exe close
GOTO :goforit

:after
endlocal
@ECHO ON
c:\Util\id3\id3.exe -M -t "%a%_%%f" -a %a% -l %t% *.%e%
REM c:\Util\id3\id3 -a "Author_Name" -t "Disc_Title %f" *.mp3
cd /d %OLDDIR%
cmd /c wizmo.exe open
goto :eof


:goforit
ECHO goforit %e% Transcoding %2
SET /a y=0
SET /a PADDED=0%y%
FOR /R D:\ %%G IN (D:\*.cda) DO (CALL :SUB_VLC "%%G")
GOTO :after

:help
@ECHO Syntax: RIP Artist[artist] Subdir[disc1] Format[[mp3]/wav]
GOTO :eof


:TEST_VLC
ECHO After ripping routine


:SUB_VLC
call SET /a y=y+1
echo begin padding
echo pad with your desired width - 1 leading zeroes
call SET PADDED=0%y%
echo slice off any zeroes you don't need -- BEWARE, this can truncate the value
echo the 2 at the end is the number of desired digits
SET PADDED=%PADDED:~-2%
REM end padding
ECHO %e% Transcoding %2 file  %PADDED%
REM Here's where the actual transcoding/conversion happens. The next line
REM fires off a command to VLC.exe with the relevant arguments:
ECHO "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" -I http cdda:///D:/ --cdda-track=!y! :sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=%e%,ab=320,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access="file",mux=raw,dst="%t%!PADDING!.%e%"} vlc://quit
IF %e%==mp3 CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" -I http cdda:///D:/ --cdda-track=!y! :sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=%e%,ab=320,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access="file",mux=raw,dst="%t%!PADDED!.%e%"} vlc://quit
IF %e%==wav CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" -I http cdda:///D:/ --cdda-track=!y! :sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=s16l,channels=2}:std{access="file",mux=wav,dst="%t%!PADDED!.%e%"} vlc://quit
:eof
```

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using exactly? WMP received feature changes with Windows 8, one of those changes removed some of the Media features unless you upgraded to `Windows 8 with Media Center` while `Windows 10` retired Media Center some of those changes still apply.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro... it doesn't show a precise version number in 'About' but its getting all the push updates from MS... including the August big update.

Comment: 'Winver' is good to know about

Comment: Version 1607 Build 14393.321

Answer (score 0):

1) In `.bat`, in some cases, you should use `%%` instead of one `%`.

2) I think problem may line in different thing. You should debug the script - 
add this line in bottom:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 123 > nul
```

and then execute the bat file, and see the logs of execution, what happened successfully and what not.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where would I change the ** to *? and what is the purpose of the ping statement at bottom?